# How do I search in Gmail by specific number of people?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

When I do `from: a@gmail.com to: b@gmail.com` in Gmail, I only want to see the results that involve 1 on 1 mails from a to b. If c@gmail.com is also part of "to" address, the mail should be ignored.

Is there any search criteria for that in Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you're hoping. You'd have to do an exclusion in your search.

```
from:a@gmail.com to:b@gmail.com - to:c@gmail.com
```

Comment: Too bad, I do not know what c@gmail.com would be for each mail.